# Docker Beta on OS X: configure where images and logs are saved

Tags: macos, docker

I would like Docker to save local image and log files on the second disk of my machine. Is there any configuration file where I can specify a directory?

Answer (score 0):

OSX/Windows runs Boot2docker, it boot a virtual machine in VirtualBox, link to docker command inside the VM to your shell. Which means, it is in the VM. If you want to change to location for capacity propose, just move the VM files via VirtualBox.

Comment: Thank you, but that is for the previous version. The new public beta version does not use VirtualBox anymore.